# Variable not translating into selector - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To make my Jquery more flexible I've pulled the selector out and I'm trying to access it through a variable, but both variables for both selectors don't appear to be working. I'm sure it'll be something simple that I'm missing and can't see, but I just can't find it.

Jquery

```
var accordion = "#accordion";
var accordionextra = accordion + " .panel-heading img'";

$(accordionextra).hide();

$(accordion).find('.panel-collapse').each(function() {
   //Do Something
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Collapsible Group Item #1
                            <img src="image/check.png" class="pull-right check" />
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control class1" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control class1" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                Collapsible Group Item #2
                                <img src="image/check.png" class="pull-right check" />
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control class2" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control class2" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="class2"> Check me out
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                Collapsible Group Item #3
                                <img src="image/check.png" class="pull-right check" />
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: On which context do you call your snippet? Just sounds like you are trying to targeting element before available in DOM

Comment: Remove the `'` in `var accordionextra = accordion + " .panel-heading img'";`

Comment: Yep - that got it - thought it would be something simple

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf But then `$(accordion).find('.panel-collapse')` was already working?!

Comment: I don't understand how using a variable makes it more flexible? It just adds more lines of unnecessary code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks is just a typo in

```
 var accordionextra = accordion + " .panel-heading img'";
```

should be

```
 var accordionextra = accordion + " .panel-heading img";
```

i test it here and works fine...
https://jsfiddle.net/vgpdzL81/